# $\mathcal{su}(3)$ irreps in the fermionic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, representation-theory, fermions, lie-algebra

> Consider the fermionic oscillator, for $d=3$ degrees of freedom, with the Hamiltonian
> $$H=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^3(a_{F_j}^{\dagger} a_{F_j}-a_{F_j} a_{F_j}^{\dagger})$$
>
> - Use fermionic annihilation and creation operators to construct a representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(3)=\mathfrak{u}(1)+\mathfrak{su}(3)$ on the fermionic state space $\mathcal{H}_F$. Which irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ occur in this state space? Picking a basis $X_j$ of $\mathfrak{u}(3)$ and bases for each irreducible representation you find, what are the representation matrices (for each $X_j$) for each such irreducible representation.

I don't understand how to fill all the questions of this problem. For $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ I can use the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda_j$ and their representation in the fermionic space is given by $U'_{\lambda_i} = \sum_{jk} a^\dagger_j (\lambda_i)_{jk}a_k$. I don't know how to determine from here the rest of the points. Specially when it says

> Picking a basis $X_j$ of $\mathfrak{u}(3)$ and basis for each irreducible representation...

Is it not that the $\lambda_j$ and $H$ are already a basis for $\mathfrak{u}(3)$?

Comment: Review the [Jordan-Schwinger map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map). Oscillators anticommute, so your irreps will be antisymmetric. Make sure you have absolutely, unequivocally, no problems with su(2) first! Only then move on to su(3). The antisymmetric combination of two triplets, for instance, is the antitriplet; so *what* do you get by tensoring the (triplet) Gell-Mann matrices? Do you *see* how the 3x3 matrices come about?

Comment: I'm more lost now, why would I need to tensor Gell-Mann matrices? What I can see is that some of the Gell-mann matrices are of the form $\mathbb{1} \otimes \sigma_{xy}$, but then is this not equivalent of using at some point $U'_{\lambda}$? What about the reducible representations? Shouldn't be similar as when one computes the "Schwinger representation" for two bosonic harmonic oscillators?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I voted up a few days ago. I wait always a little to choose the favorite answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after you have test-driven the [Jordan construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map#Fermions) for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, you may consider the triplet rep of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, for fermion oscillators. Let's call them $b,b^\dagger$ to avoid confusion with the bosonic ones. Imply summation over repeated indices.

You may then define the fermion bilinears
$$
\Lambda =b^\dagger_j b_j, \qquad \Lambda^a= b^\dagger_j \lambda^a_{jk} b_k,
$$
and so, e.g.,
$$\Lambda^1= b^\dagger_1 b_2 +  b^\dagger_2 b_1, \qquad \Lambda^4= b^\dagger_1 b_3 + b^\dagger_3 b_1,\qquad \Lambda^7= i(b^\dagger_3 b_2 - b^\dagger_2 b_3) ,
$$
etc...

Confirm by use of the anticommutation relations for the oscillators that, indeed,
$$
[\Lambda, \Lambda^a]=0, \qquad [\Lambda^1, \Lambda^4]=i \Lambda^7,
$$
*just like the Gell-Mann matrices*! So the $\Lambda^a$ are the triplet representation when acting on triplet states $b^\dagger_j|0\rangle$.

Proceed to tensor two  **3**s,  antisymmetrically, by dint of the self-antisymmetrizing fermion oscillators, to obtain the customary $\bar{\mathbf 3}$, etc...

Unlike the bosonic oscillator irreps of the construction which can grow indefinitely, the nilpotency of the fermion oscillators limits you to merely 7 states: $b^\dagger_i|0\rangle; \epsilon_{ijk}b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k|0\rangle ; b^\dagger_1 b^\dagger_2 b^\dagger_3|0\rangle$, and that's that! The last state is a self-evident singlet, the first the triplet, and the second the antitriplet.

Observe the action of $\Lambda^1$ on it: do you see it flips the first with the second component, just as in the triplet, but with an overall minus sign?